# Concept of "client callback" in the lib(libmicrohttp-dev)

Tags: linux, c

I am trying to programming a embedded server using the lib(libmicrohttpd-dev,MHD).But I have not got a clear understanding of the concept "client callback".

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you might also consider [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/) or [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) in addition of [libmicrohttpd](http://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) as HTTP server libraries.

<sup>IMHO, `libonion` is easier to use than `libmicrohttpd`.... But YMMV.</sup>

A [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29) is a function that you register to a [framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_framework) library which will be called (in some circumstances) by that library. Often, you also register a pointer to some of your data in addition of the function pointer, and your function gets called with your data.

In C, callbacks should usually have some client data because C does not know about [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). The way to emulate closures in C is to provide a *C* function and the closed values, which you group in a client data structure.